# How can I find out if a tab is hidden when loading in Chrome using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit

How can I find out if a tab is hidden when loading in Chrome using JavaScript? I've tried using `onfocus`/`onblur` and `document.webkitHidden`.

`document.webkitHidden` works great in all situations, except when I first resume a session and a window opens several tabs at once.  In that case, `document.webkitHidden` is false in all tabs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's dirty, but you could check how often requestAnimationFrame is running in combination with  document.webkitHidden. Chrome throttles requestAnimationFrame when a tab isn't active.